# Difference between から and で in context of because

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-で, particle-から

So, I was going across the particle で and から and I found that, both of them have the function of "because". Following are the examples

E.g. of using で as because

> 病気で旅行に行けなかった (Because I was sick, I couldn’t go on the trip)
>
> 台風で電車が止まった (The train stopped on account of the typhoon)
>
> 風で扉が開きました（Wind opened the door)

E.g. of using から as because

> あのレストランは安いからいつも混んでいます (That restaurant is inexpensive, so it’s always crowded)
>
> 忙しかったから私たちは公園へ行きませんでした (We didn’t go to the park because we were too busy)

What's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

As for the meaning, I think they are the same. As for when to use から or で, you can notice if you read your sentences carefully. A noun is placed before で, and a sentence or verb is placed before から.