# Problems with から, て form and で (because)

Tags: grammar, particles, て-form, particle-で, particle-から

Well, searching around the web I came across this post ([Difference between から and で in context of because](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/74184/difference-between-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-and-%E3%81%A7-in-context-of-because)) that had a similar problem, but it did not resolve mine. I found these three sentences:

夏休みがありますから、夏が一番好きです。

通りにまよって、おくれました。

じゅうたいで、おくれました。

I kind of understand the difference between the last sentence and the other two (there is a noun before で), but in the other two there is a verb and I am not able to tell when to use から or the て form.

Comment: See if this one helps: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/78280/what-is-the-difference-in-nuance-between-using-%e3%81%a6-form-and-%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89-to-express-so-or/78283#78283 Note that て and で work the same way. て is just the te-form of the copula (だ)

Comment: Then から and て/で are interchangeable? I would just have to be careful with て possibly meaning 'and'?

Comment: Maybe this help you: https://simplyjapanese.tumblr.com/post/23885493892

Comment: Yes, that helped me a lot! Everything clear now, thank you both so much!